# According to the selected language either from application or from device can I convert the language in application?

Tags: ios

I have to make my application multi language supported on the selection of particular radio buttons(i.e. English, French, German etc...). For that what I have to do? any external framework or API is required?

To do so from where I have to start & if any inbuilt method is there then please suggest me.

I want to add another thing, can it be possible according to the selected language of the device we can get all the effect in application same as the selected device language?

Comment: Before posting question you should first see in the iPhone SDK documentation. You will get most of the things there.

Answer (score 1):

In code you can access current locale and language that user set in Settings:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString *currentLanguage = [languages objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"Current Locale: %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);
NSLog(@"Current language: %@", currentLanguage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to support Localization in the app for all the hardcoded strings. 
The below code returns the code for the device language selected. eg: en, zh, etc..

```
let langStr = Locale.current.languageCode
```

Based on the code returned, the repective Localizable.strings file displays the value for the strings.